# Why does 何も mean "anything"?

Tags: meaning, particle-も, polarity-items

That is, why does adding the 「も」 particle to question words give it a universal, for lack of a better term, word. It's not even always required to be there, as in sentences like

> お好み焼きが何よりいい
>   *Okonomiyaki is better than anything*

which is just as correct as using 「よりも」 as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I don't have the time to write an answer right now, but might I interest you in [this blog post on the topic](https://namakajiri.net/nikki/dare-ka-and-dare-mo/)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is related to one of the meanings of も.

> も - *prt.* A marker which indicates emphasis.

It's used in sentences like:

> 私は漢字を一つも知らない。
>
> I don't even know 1 kanji.

This can be used the same way with 何:

> 何も知らない、ジョン・スノウ。
>
> (lit.) You don't even know [one] thing, Jon Snow.
>
> You don't know anything, Jon Snow.

In this sense it doesn't quite make it a universal word.
It just happens that "even one thing" coincides with the more natural translation "anything".

---

To address the use of よりも, the も is the same emphasis marker. When combined with より it emphasizes the speaker's opinion that there really is nothing better than Okonomiyaki.

Comment: This grammar is exactly why there is a cell phone company named DOKOMO.  It implies that their cell coverage works anywhere.

Comment: @ajsmart Huh I never knew that. They do seem to have the best coverage.